# Nhibernate updating version column on foreign key entity

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I am using c# with Fluent NHibernate and auto mapping.

Here is some code (truncated for clarity), then I'll explain the problem.

```
public class Company
{
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
}
public class Stock 
{
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping**

```
mappings.Conventions.Add<CascadeConvention>()
    .Conventions.Add<CustomForeignKeyConvention>()
    .Conventions.Add<HasManyConvention>()
    .Conventions.Add<VersionConvention>()
```

- `CascadeConvention` just sets everything to All.
- `CustomForeignKeyConvention` removes the _id that NHibernate usually
  appends to foreign key id columns.
- `HasManyConvention` sets all `HasMany`'s to inverse.
- `VersionConvention` convertion looks like this:

  instance.Column("Version");

  instance.Default(1);

The problem is that when I insert a new stock record, Nhibernate also updates the version number on the related `Company`.
If I had an `IList<Stock>` property on the `Company` then that would make sense but I don't.

I've done a lot of reading around:

- [NHibernate emitting extraneous update statements regardless of proper Inverse (fluent nhibernate) settings on relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150260/nhibernate-emitting-extraneous-update-statements-regardless-of-proper-inverse-f)
- [Cascade Save-Update in NHibernate and version column](http://frankmao.com/2011/05/02/cascade-save-update-in-nhibernate-and-version-column/)
- [NHibernate Reference - Chapter 17. Example: Parent/Child](http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/nhibernate-reference-1.2.0/example-parentchild.html)
- [Ayende @ Rahien - NHibernate Mapping](http://ayende.com/blog/3936/nhibernate-mapping-property)

From these, I've tried a whole bunch of things including adding `.Not.OptimisticLock()` all over the place. I even added an `IList<Stock>` property on `Company` so that I could specifically set it as `Inverse`, `Not.OptimisticLock`, etc. Nothing I do seems to make any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We eventually sorted this by moving to a Session-per-request paradigm. Not sure why it was going wrong or why this fixed it. I wrote numerous unit tests to try and reproduce the behaviour in a more controlled environment without success.

In any case, it works now. There are good reasons session-per-request is often given as the best practice way to manage NHibernate sessions in a web application.